# Can't import task listeners defined in separate file

Tags: gradle

I have a file `MyTaskListeners.gradle` located somewhere and in each of my projects I want to import this file and only add the desired listeners.

E.g. `MyTaskListeners.gradle` might have `TimingsListener`, `FlowListener`, `SomeOtherListener1`, `SomeOtherListener1`, ... and in a certain projects `build.gradle` i would like you write something like:

```
apply from: 'utils.gradle'
gradle.addListener new TaskFlowListener()
```

How can I get the classes from `MyTaskListeners.gradle` to be available and known in the projects `build.gradle`? With what I have written above the classes are not known

```
unable to resolve class TaskFlowListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes (and even methods for that matter) defined in script plugins are not directly accessible outside of that individual script. If you have utility classes that you want on your build script classpath and want to avoid packaging/publishing them as an individual project, you can use the [buildSrc project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources).